# Can ColdFusion do this in fewer lines?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a query that looks like this:

```
    DATEUPLOADED             ID     TYPE
1   2017-08-14 15:47:45.0   2405507 D
2   2017-08-14 15:47:44.0   2405506 D
3   2017-08-16 08:43:58.0   2407829 S
4   2017-08-16 08:43:41.0   2407828 S
5   2017-08-18 13:13:29.0   2411567 C
6   2017-08-18 13:16:20.0   2411571 P
7   2017-08-18 15:42:39.0   2411753 C
8   2017-08-18 15:44:39.0   2411759 C
9   2017-08-18 15:45:14.0   2411760 C
10  2017-08-18 15:45:48.0   2411761 C
11  2017-08-18 16:39:05.0   2411849 A
12  2017-08-18 16:40:12.0   2411853 V
```

Is it possible to do the following in fewer lines:

```
<cfquery name="GetCount" dbtype="query" >
   SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TheAboveQuery WHERE Type = 'C'
</cfquery>

<cfif GetCount.RecordCount gt 0 > 
     Do something
</cfif>
```

Comment: Probably, but you might sacrificing readability.

Comment: @DanBracuk I'm more or less just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you are looking to achieve, this might be ok:

```
<cfif arrayFind(TheAboveQuery ['type'], 'C') gt 0>
do something
</cfif>
```

Comment: I like this. I don't think it's less readable, really. It's silly that coldfusion treats the query as an array though.

Comment: Prior to `arrayFind`, you had to use `ListFind(ValueList(TheAboveQuery.Type), "C")`.  If "type" values are mixed case, be sure to use `arrayFindNoCase` or `ListFindNocase`... or use `UPPER(Type) = 'C'` to the query-of-queries.

Comment: Note, that code will work on Adobe CF, but not out of the box on Lucee Server.  Instead of implicitly treating CF query columns as an array, Lucee has a function to get it as an array: QueryColumnData().

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify the CF engine or version you need this to run on.  There are some even shorter ways, and whether or not you add line breaks in them can make them a one-liner.  I'd caution, it's not a competition, so don't be afraid of a few extra lines for the sake of readability!

This is nice and tidy and should work on Lucee Server and Adobe 2016

```
if( TheAboveQuery.filter( function(r){ return r.type=='C'; }).recordCount ) {
  // do something
}
```

If you're on Lucee 5, you can shave off a few more characters by using a Lambda (arrow function) instead of a traditional closure but it's unlikely that you're really benefiting much at this point.

```
if( TheAboveQuery.filter( (r) => return r.type=='C' ).recordCount ) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: I'm on cf10, but this is pretty slick.